# Do WebDriver implicit waits affect both findElement AND findElements?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Or do they only affect findElement? For example, if I want to test for an element that does not exist on the page, do I want to use findElement (which will be slow due to implicit waiting), or can I use `findElements(..).size() == 0` (for example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Implicit wait is firm to the driver instance and as soon as you instantiate the driver it will apply to any findElement mechanism. Explicit wait is your best bet in terms of waiting for the element since explicit wait does not have influence on the entire driver instance.

*Please note Implicit wait also has influence over explicit waits. Mixing them both together is never recommended. See [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question & found an answer in `findElement(By by)` documentation (in WebDriver.java).

```
/**
   * Find the first {@link WebElement} using the given method.
   * This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the time of execution.
   * The findElement(..) invocation will return a matching row, or try again repeatedly until
   * the configured timeout is reached.
   *
   * findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use {@link #findElements(By)}
   * and assert zero length response instead.
   *
   * @param by The locating mechanism
   * @return The first matching element on the current page
   * @throws NoSuchElementException If no matching elements are found
   * @see org.openqa.selenium.By
   * @see org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Timeouts
   */
  WebElement findElement(By by);
```

in short:

- `findElement` is affected by the 'implicit wait'
- `findElement` should not be used to look for non-present elements
- for non-present elements, use `findElements`